# Laravel three-way pivot contraints

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent, pivot

I ran into a problem where I have to connect three models in laravel.

Model 1: Licences

```
licences_table
    id
    name
```

Model 2: Disciplines

```
disciplines_table
    id
    name
```

Model 3: Levels

```
levels_table
  id
  name
  weight
```

So a licence can have many disciplines, and disciplines can have many levels.

But levels with disciplines must be unique for certain licence.

I also created a pivot table with three foreign keys:

```
discipline_levels_table
   level_id
   discipline_id
   licence_id
```

I have defined relationships between these three models using belongsToMany.

The problem is, when I try to get all licences with their disciplines and levels like this:`Licence::with(array("disciplines","disciplines.levels"))->get();`

I get levels that are connected to disciplines only and NOT to licence AND disciplines.

I would like to get all levels that are connected to each discipline and each licence.

How to accomplish that?

Should I define a different relationship between models?

Or should I structure a different query?

Comment: What you are describing sounds like a many licenses to many disciplines with an extra level field on the pivot table and unique index on all three fields, or a one license to many disciplines where disciplines have the license foreign key and a level field and a unique index on the license_id and level field. Does that make sense?